# Cocos2d : How to check Sprite Frame Name is available or not?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I'm new to Cocos2d framework.

I am trying to create `CCSprite` from `sharedSpriteFrameCache` with image name by :

```
// In init method
[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"imgFile.plist"];

// In separate method
CCSprite *spBubble = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"img1.png"];
```

Now sometimes it get crashed at `spBubble = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"img1.png"];` 
as it couldn't load image.

**crash log :**

> cocos2d: CCSpriteFrameCache: Frame 'img1.png' not found

So I tried to check if img1.png is available or not by

```
if(![CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"img1.png"])
{

}
```

But it also crashed in `if` condition.

**So How can I check that img1.png is available or not ?**

If not then I can load again by 
`[[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"imgFile.plist"];`

Comment: I don't think you need to check that as it is automatically done when you load the frames. Are you sure the file img1.png exists and included in your project ?

Comment: @giorashc: yes img1 is exists. Also, it loads at first time

Comment: @giorashc: please check my answer I got solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the solution.

In `CCSprite.m`, in `+(id)spriteWithSpriteFrameName:(NSString*)spriteFrameName` method `CCSpriteFrame` is created. When it does not found the image, the returned frame is `nil`. So I've directly used that code to check if frame is nil or not.

```
CCSpriteFrame *frame = [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:@"img1.png"];    
if(!frame)
{     
    // load image from .plist   
    [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"imgFile.plist"];
}
```

This trick worked for me.